# How to read Text file with multi delimiter and arrange the columns accordingly in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, delimiter

I have a text file with 2 delimiters which includes in columns and the rows, I need it to be read and arrange the columns to corresponding row value.
Please find the file copied below.

20180831,500,20160908;20160909;20160912;20160913;20160914;20160915;20160916;20160919;20160920;20160921;20160922;20160923;20160926;20160927;20160928;20160929;20160930;20161003;20161004;20161005;20161006;20161007;20161010;20161011;20161012;20161013;20161014;20161017;20161018;20161019;20161020;20161021;20161024;20161025;20161026;20161027;20161028;20161031;20161101;20161102;20161103;20161104;20161107;20161108;20161109;20161110;20161111;20161114;20161115;20161116;20161117;20161118;20161121;20161122;20161123;20161124;20161125;20161128;20161129;20161130;20161201;20161202;20161205;20161206;20161207;20161208;20161209;20161212;20161213;20161214;20161215;20161216;20161219;20161220;20161221;20161222;20161223;20161226;20161227;20161228;20161229;20161230;20170102;20170103;20170104;20170105;20170106;20170109;20170110;20170111;20170112;20170113;20170116;20170117;20170118;20170119;20170120;20170123;20170124;20170125;20170126;20170127;20170130;20170131;20170201;20170202;20170203;20170206;20170207;20170208;20170209;20170210;20170213;20170214;20170215;20170216;20170217;20170220;20170221;20170222;20170223;20170224;20170227;20170228;20170301;20170302;20170303;20170306;20170307;20170308;20170309;20170310;20170313;20170314;20170315;20170316;20170317;20170320;20170321;20170322;20170323;20170324;20170327;20170328;20170329;20170330;20170331;20170403;20170404;20170405;20170406;20170407;20170410;20170411;20170412;20170413;20170414;20170417;20170418;20170419;20170420;20170421;20170424;20170425;20170426;20170427;20170428;20170501;20170502;20170503;20170504;20170505;20170508;20170509;20170510;20170511;20170512;20170515;20170516;20170517;20170518;20170519;20170522;20170523;20170524;20170525;20170526;20170529;20170530;20170531;20170601;20170602;20170605;20170606;20170607;20170608;20170609;20170612;20170613;20170614;20170615;20170616;20170619;20170620;20170621;20170622;20170623;20170626;20170627;20170628;20170629;20170630;20170703;20170704;20170705;20170706;20170707;20170710;20170711;20170712;20170713;20170714;20170717;20170718;20170719;20170720;20170721;20170724;20170725;20170726;20170727;20170728;20170731;20170801;20170802;20170803;20170804;20170807;20170808;20170809;20170810;20170811;20170814;20170815;20170816;20170817;20170818;20170821;20170822;20170823;20170824;20170825;20170828;20170829;20170830;20170831;20170901;20170904;20170905;20170906;20170907;20170908;20170911;20170912;20170913;20170914;20170915;20170918;20170919;20170920;20170921;20170922;20170925;20170926;20170927;20170928;20170929;20171002;20171003;20171004;20171005;20171006;20171009;20171010;20171011;20171012;20171013;20171016;20171017;20171018;20171019;20171020;20171023;20171024;20171025;20171026;20171027;20171030;20171031;20171101;20171102;20171103;20171106;20171107;20171108;20171109;20171110;20171113;20171114;20171115;20171116;20171117;20171120;20171121;20171122;20171123;20171124;20171127;20171128;20171129;20171130;20171201;20171204;20171205;20171206;20171207;20171208;20171211;20171212;20171213;20171214;20171215;20171218;20171219;20171220;20171221;20171222;20171225;20171226;20171227;20171228;20171229;20180101;20180102;20180103;20180104;20180105;20180108;20180109;20180110;20180111;20180112;20180115;20180116;20180117;20180118;20180119;20180122;20180123;20180124;20180125;20180126;20180129;20180130;20180131;20180201;20180202;20180205;20180206;20180207;20180208;20180209;20180212;20180213;20180214;20180215;20180216;20180219;20180220;20180221;20180222;20180223;20180226;20180227;20180228;20180301;20180302;20180305;20180306;20180307;20180308;20180309;20180312;20180313;20180314;20180315;20180316;20180319;20180320;20180321;20180322;20180323;20180326;20180327;20180328;20180329;20180330;20180402;20180403;20180404;20180405;20180406;20180409;20180410;20180411;20180412;20180413;20180416;20180417;20180418;20180419;20180420;20180423;20180424;20180425;20180426;20180427;20180430;20180501;20180502;20180503;20180504;20180507;20180508;20180509;20180510;20180511;20180514;20180515;20180516;20180517;20180518;20180521;20180522;20180523;20180524;20180525;20180528;20180529;20180530;20180531;20180601;20180604;20180605;20180606;20180607;20180608;20180611;20180612;20180613;20180614;20180615;20180618;20180619;20180620;20180621;20180622;20180625;20180626;20180627;20180628;20180629;20180702;20180703;20180704;20180705;20180706;20180709;20180710;20180711;20180712;20180713;20180716;20180717;20180718;20180719;20180720;20180723;20180724;20180725;20180726;20180727;20180730;20180731;20180801;20180802;20180803;20180806;20180807;20180808 
****Above has header****

2nd line below

20180831,AB,AB(ABC),DAY,NEEL,68091023,N/A,-354.82;384.08;-246.55;49.98;39.13;5.77;340.1;-36.98;-1.48;262.02;-691.67;247.28;-296.11;279.61;-34.25;-12.53;-159.06;-10.25;298.09;-433.42;85.91;-159.03;346.27;318.53;291.9;-34.53;221.19;22.48;208.92;149.85;132.57;487.92;-72.11;199.62;-486.97;141.88;14.87;-133.01;-763.35;-639.21;346.47;-290.09;671.25;74.31;153.49;504.56;-268.95;611.91;-11.93;63.92;12.39;282.09;-6.7;32.45;293.79;-145.43;-253.79;195.89;-150.28;-175.75;28.85;-382.97;-530.76;8.09;-49.06;720.66;368.94;-466.41;-144.49;3.7;647.08;-7.12;5.06;497.6;-496.75;-79.71;37.1;0.01;-65.57;363.7;-410.57;-663.33;-62.91;910.01;-469.26;-670.76;49.73;1.79;-487.37;524.23;-1456.22;435.94;-222.4;-842.35;292.53;534.9;-500.49;-496.79;-231.19;288.36;244.6;-118.32;62.24;-984.33;256.95;-362.56;426.93;122.32;354.91;-207.62;318.21;251.18;215.06;-47.45;405.48;-760.56;68.12;144.39;344.78;218.65;-859.37;138.99;-210.59;-4.12;542.05;183.66;-312.6;-235.35;204.2;-540.99;-301.36;-251.41;-278.36;211.65;143.12;-786.92;-140.46;-211.53;-412.62;-41.51;67.68;-17.65;-639.5;76.28;661.66;98.24;295.36;127.32;43.21;-108.07;-102.63;-44.01;207.46;-129.42;-46.7;-75.23;6.35;-61.55;-464.17;-81.79;-538.02;400.63;-1198.01;-221.39;58.02;307.99;-434.08;-15.48;140.68;-23.6;-178.8;-364.51;600.55;477.87;222.03;117.05;-400.55;-502.3;-761.22;-457.27;113.13;-573.72;-490.68;227.04;198.24;-122.74;249.68;-43.05;-189.05;-249.44;166.56;-359.36;136.71;-128.02;27.94;398.96;363.93;-181.67;55.83;-505.28;825.2;-188.74;53.31;303.72;-18.43;-157.38;-192.75;-0.22;-742.95;-760.92;-254.4;-131.59;390.49;169.85;76.68;-595.03;54.43;129.98;-82.63;-89.46;46.55;-429.25;-90.92;-962.34;407.94;-409.55;-549.41;13.81;-431.23;409.1;-562.46;-168.17;-125.36;-596.18;-59.28;-194.05;436.35;7.96;-101.22;468.66;-232.08;-417.88;96.67;508.19;161.43;-228.56;-131.2;-332.12;247.8;-268.74;-25.15;18.64;3.09;-1799.04;584.33;300.61;121.83;-306.41;65.69;-251.85;-475.35;-171.13;310.68;305.77;75.68;322.16;-640.95;60.56;-176.59;-64.56;556.77;-379.28;558.14;571.01;487.13;-476.7;82.16;299.65;47.65;-59.58;322.56;234.44;-221.29;-558.07;-358.48;-63.83;-179.16;384.59;425.82;-52.41;-658.15;368.09;262.06;-0.52;-287.93;533.48;697.85;-239.78;-19.21;104.74;-254.84;450.74;221.16;17.71;-102.98;-323.55;-182.74;55.38;-725.87;-486.28;436.38;-133.2;156.84;201.69;-238.54;-512.39;-621.52;-105.14;410.89;238.21;-559.51;274.4;115.76;126.66;229.33;-48.03;336.05;-229.25;322.95;-45.86;-322.04;36.81;-70.07;-7.02;-395.89;13.32;155.05;0;-1.97;-416.21;-282.64;-364.35;-32.93;-411.47;210.01;-879.42;372.69;428.64;312.79;-432.52;-491.86;-669.34;-939;583.58;-156.69;-319.71;35.98;85.76;-234.2;-848.61;-683.86;204.11;417.64;-644.47;-26.94;213.36;33.12;28.57;174.15;20.19;302.05;30.46;24.69;-645.64;345.18;-1258.02;318.93;458.29;70.92;208.94;24.96;145.03;59.72;228.46;413.88;139.23;-963.85;34.84;-477.33;-53.28;382.67;309.98;18.94;-326.74;118.8;137.71;342.96;-466.65;338.14;-82.02;-152.74;-152.02;-686.02;312.77;230.12;136.64;18.77;-4.33;355.42;-215.04;306;-55.14;-347.26;-223.89;-30.43;265.07;-67.42;-437.53;243.03;-204.27;95.08;432.91;160.69;-198.21;216.55;127.92;542.88;149.84;148.2;215.48;26.63;315.82;-54.29;389.03;-212.82;-150.24;-221.72;-217.23;745.47;0.88;69.79;259.66;-163.03;-159.66;407.31;-89.77;469.98;-69.52;219.83;-258.98;-243.93;56.98;-237.3;239.29;-828.84;-159.33;153.38;-331.87;101.6;188.39;698.07;155.01;-112.26;208.6;-21.58;-123.6;-414.09;-187.89;128.64;405.83;127.77;-405.76;144.03;-258.42;93.09;-373.83;-240.89;21.49;280.77;-287.3;290.29;190.01;-527.26;261.7;302.17;137.66;-813.5;101.53;14.68;109.97;158.86;133.71;-389.17;49.74;229.13;134.51;189.52;33.66;-380.63;199.17;,FV,IFRS,EURUSD,VANILLA AMERICAN DOWN AND OUT,FX,FX,APOMIDLLOH,HSBC ABCABCCOP012F,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,n/a,6989.89,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N,N/A,ALL IN

3rd Line below

20180831,AB,AB(ABC),DAY,NEEL,68091024,N/A,-225.31;241.69;-182.21;61.07;-34.8;-82.26;250.41;19.86;-26.12;186.56;-483.26;157.11;-185.38;181.99;-46.49;-8.49;-88.77;42.76;230.01;-274.4;118.57;-127.93;295.63;99.87;243.29;60.26;265.43;-10.48;166.57;99.09;97.09;366.77;-46.87;144.68;-361.24;86.64;63.67;-110.68;-609.7;-562.42;343.23;-233.22;547.79;165.96;-15.32;299.13;-308.15;352.49;39.55;-14.53;1.46;177.59;95.52;21.93;223.04;-167.52;-149.53;143.87;-147.82;-163.28;20.25;-285.65;-349.33;-1.86;-46.16;461.91;187.65;-337.32;-71.71;13.89;234.47;-23.77;1.49;396.93;-332.37;-32.67;4.78;0.01;-21.66;266.38;-316.21;-496.71;-34.73;725.96;-297.71;-511.58;109.99;-2.47;-317.59;337.71;-1080.07;309.32;-129.02;-564.27;209.74;352.99;-363.21;-355.81;-182.3;164.32;132.17;-90;-48.18;-694.94;247.04;-280.49;338.27;27.21;158.78;-237.41;-337.56;124.48;153.73;-34.55;278.58;-574.31;-19.89;27.02;273.36;59.97;-456.84;135.87;-118.42;50.29;413.99;169.47;-52.59;-137.33;174.51;2.46;-244.42;-100.99;-191.31;171.69;87.75;-499.64;-113.05;-247.64;-254.39;-61.67;78.2;50.18;-487.67;60.21;434.7;90.7;274.67;129.88;35.8;-110.09;-33.68;-127.52;192.76;-124.66;-91.26;-52.36;13.23;-58.36;-360.25;4.85;-404.75;263.53;-593.26;-159.24;25.39;324.96;-352.38;-19.77;133.74;33.51;-182.06;-226.5;584.8;451.25;75.17;109.21;-270.76;-401.13;-611.83;-364.09;123.7;-422.83;-345;154;75.9;33.03;177.38;-82.9;-186.85;-171.67;160.87;-218.44;72.9;-84.16;-91.7;369.67;306.38;-110.28;65.66;-449.84;606.43;-108.26;88.37;214.55;-115.45;-138.33;-134.02;0.1;-600.67;-687.07;-128.93;-100.27;336.7;88.01;9.57;-409.4;66.1;141.16;-72.4;-117.41;5;-273.92;-77.04;-817.25;337.05;-313.06;-334.32;17.42;-362.57;240.99;-450.64;-94.85;-92.07;-468.26;-74.33;-177.78;354.59;84.45;-64.95;252.37;-215.31;-280.7;101.2;392.1;105.44;-201.33;-87.18;-238.71;197.5;-199.92;23.44;36.42;-4.52;-1410.94;399.68;241.08;117.02;-224.98;40.58;-223.59;-360.81;-153.66;324.19;249.16;23.57;108.77;-514.36;78.9;-147.32;-60.37;409.93;-326.03;434.14;539.96;437.8;-372.54;148.79;237.26;82.84;-100.03;278.74;200.74;-134.66;-421.45;-307.5;48.36;-83.65;273.12;341.79;-18.46;-556.56;312.07;211.08;33.33;-256.04;278.84;522.54;-171.9;58.16;64.36;-235.74;395.3;205.71;57.5;-88.76;-266.48;-83.37;39.51;-606.34;-408.56;431.18;-79.85;94.24;159.14;-167.58;-351.05;-552.76;-25.71;303.65;143.28;-454.83;198.76;135.42;-183.33;150.84;-103.39;261.39;-197.19;178.17;-39.02;-197.11;32.99;-91.95;-24.31;-371.15;-37.64;137.05;0;0.06;-359.17;-229.49;-296.02;-37.28;-247.81;176.63;-320.27;291.24;413.05;301.77;-291.21;-451.46;-501.47;-749.84;599.97;-167.27;-323.69;-4.66;111.41;-116.53;-707.6;-666.34;190.5;254.55;-494.85;20.76;97.46;37.1;-6.13;70.93;93.92;159.62;-40.8;39.18;-458.11;352.94;-982.75;225.4;396.93;-4.66;252.85;5.45;110.32;110.66;158.14;310.06;55.32;-687.44;61.49;-376.53;-82.57;293;310.29;27.48;-219.1;-32.8;117.9;232.76;-374.43;275.08;-88.54;-127.23;-81.19;-525.72;209.69;148.68;136.3;23.63;3.5;264.37;-164.59;263.56;-56.44;-215.27;-151.57;-51.13;304.57;-18.67;-300.63;193.02;-186.33;74.77;261.05;128.81;-218.38;99.3;34.85;435.25;159.37;8.66;118.18;30.35;262.9;-55.89;262.9;-185.26;-64.14;-76.79;-159.95;503.93;-82.8;70.84;212.3;-151.93;-150.95;197.02;40.76;353.07;-87.81;47.49;-418.98;-165.99;340.08;-109.2;166.25;-620.87;-145.3;83.4;-251.78;97.95;72.42;495.94;89.64;-120.12;121.8;12.04;-119.81;-267.62;-122.4;115.38;279.04;8.92;-230.66;23.67;-158.83;77.99;-258.75;-80.36;57.85;161.39;-235.82;226.45;142.65;-381.96;178.69;210.11;43.18;-558.52;95.92;-16.77;75.87;141.94;108.84;-252.42;24.95;164.95;52.55;99.83;-28.87;-270.55;111.18;,FV,IFRS,EURUSD,VANILLA AMERICAN DOWN AND OUT,FX,FX,APOMIDLLOH,HSBC ABCABCCOP012F,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,n/a,6003.05,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N,N/A,ALL IN

I have tried using

```
pd.read_csv('C:\delimiters.txt', header = 'infer',sep='[,,;]')
```

it is sorted but the column is not arranged.
[Please check the image when the file opened in note padd ++ looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8awf5.png)

[I want the data to be like this atleast when read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhDQ0.png)

[After running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpCrf.png)

Comment: Is all of the text above really one line? If not, could you perhaps edit your question to make it more legible (e.g. using a code block for formatting) and to include the proper line breaks?

Comment: – Asmus  : I have edited the question, Mentioned which is first line in note pad which has header and other 2 lines with row values.

Comment: I fear there is something inherently wrong in the data you've posted: the first line has 499 ';' and 2 ',', (i.e. 501 delimiters) line 2 and 3 however have 500 ';' and 43 ',' (i.e. 543 delimiters).

Comment: To be clear, both comma and semicolon are (column) delimiters

Comment: @ smci : Yes both are columns

Comment: Karthike: yes I'm saying you should explicitly state that (unusual) requirement. Most libraries are built around the assumption that there is one fixed delimiter, at least in the default case. (There are obvious reasons why, like what if delimiter2 occurs within a text field, should it be parsed as a delimiter or not, or only if not escaped, what is the escape-char, etc. You can easily build a nightmare for the parser, and even if not, parser performance will go down. It can be easier to just fix up your input file to have one single delimiter, e.g. with sed/awk/perl/search-and-replace...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `,` use `|` for multiple separator.

```
pd.read_csv('C:\delimiters.txt', header = 'infer', index_col=False, sep='[;]')
```

Comment: - bkyada : Tried, but header goes missing and column arrangement gets changed.

Comment: @Karthike, can you edit your question to show which one is the header. I can see you added *** Above has header ***. So, the first block is header here?

Comment: while reading the file as dataframe, you can pass the option called `names` which takes a list of strings which pandas uses as column names. `df = pandas.read_csv("fileName.csv",names=["a","b","c"],sep='[,,;]')`. Read this link for [Reading CSV as DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: @ bkyada, @ Yayati Sule : I have added the image, please check when opened in note pad ++ how the data looks

Comment: thank you for you time , Please check the new image of output how it should be looking ,

Comment: @Karthike Based on your output image you might want to use only `;` as a separator.  Is your data size for the sample is Header + 2 rows x 500 Columns?

Comment: @Karthike Then try with just one sep `;` that should solve your problem.

Comment: @ bkyada : I tried nut again , the column is different and value is different. I am attaching the image

Comment: @ bkyada : 20160909 should have the value starts from 384.08

Comment: @Karthike Understood your problem now. Try `pd.read_csv('delimiter.txt',header='infer', index_col=False, sep=';')`

Comment: thank you @ bkyada : I was able to get the correct value for the header.
and also I used df1['20180831,500,20160908'].map(lambda x: str(x)[40:]) and df1['20180831,500,20160908'].str[:8] to get the required row value.
thank you very much. , can I do transpose? to get the date as row value and repeat the df1['20180831,500,20160908'] value 500 times????